# Parse string which contains multiple JSON data strings

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm facing a problem where I could not find a good looking approach to parse one string which contains multiple JSON strings, as in `{content1}{content2}{content3}`.

What is a good approach to parse this string so the result would be:

`{content1}`  `{content2}`  `{content3}`

Maybe something with Regex?

Comment: I would look into JSON.NET for parsing JSON strings into objects.

Comment: THis is not JSON format

Comment: @CuongLe This is just an example. The important part is the curly brackets, which would be used for the algorithm to know where one JSON starts and the other ends.

Comment: But can't the `content` bits also contain curly brackets, if they are supposed to be JSON?

Comment: No, not for my current use at least.

Comment: Sorry for whining but that's pretty critical information to leave out. If you call them JSON strings, it's easy to assume that the full set of valid JSON may be in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
var output = input.Split(new[] {'{', '}'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(x => "{" + x + "}")
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, and for other who stumble upon this answer, what does that actually do?

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg: The code has shown what actually does, I can add the link for more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx:

```
string input = "{content1}{content2}{content3}";
var matches = Regex.Match(input, "(?:({[^}]+}) *)*");
string[] contents = matches.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: In a case like `{ foo: { bar: 'null' } }{...}{...}`, wouldn't your regexp stop matching prematurely, i.e. at the first `}` that it encounters?

Comment: Yes, it would. But sample input does not show any case like that.

Comment: Well, it seems there were no curly brackets inside after all.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that each JSON part is an object literal, I guess you can simply split the string on `}\s*{`, as that could never occur inside valid JSON.